# Adjusting website to mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I've decided to begin with websites for mobile devices. I'm using http://mobiletest.me to check how the website would look on mobile device, without actually using my mobile all the time to check. However, when I finally made 80% of work and wanted to check on my phone it displays the site on `100% width` as a normal website not like an bigger one.

What is it I'm missing in my project to display it the right way? I have main `container` that holds all other divs inside. Maybe this might be the issue?

```
div#mobile-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by device size you mean setting the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Add this to your `head` tag and it will not give you a normal website size.

Answer (score 0):

Also can't be harmful to add:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
```